# Hide view after a few seconds using View Animator Android

Tags: android, android-animation, android-seekbar, java-threads, viewanimator

I have a seekbar which opens up using a button click event. I need to hide the seekbar after a few seconds once the user has stopped tracking the progress. Its like if the user is not using the seek bar for a period of time, seekbar automatically hides. At the moment, I'm using a thread which starts once the user stops tracking the progress, then it sleeps for 10 seconds and hide the seekbar. The problem is, Once the thread starts the user cannot change the progress until thread activity finished. Is there any other way to achieve this functionality? Any help is appreciated. Following is my code.

Button click:

```
relLayout.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            viewAnimatorSeekbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            seekBarPageIndicator.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewAnimatorSeekbar.showNext();

            return true;

        }
    });
```

Seek bar value change listener:

```
seekBarPageIndicator.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {

           Toast.makeText(getContext(), Integer.toString(progress), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            try{

                Thread.sleep(10000);
                viewAnimatorSeekbar.showNext();
                seekBarPageIndicator.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                viewAnimatorSeekbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Layout is as follows.

```
<ViewAnimator
    android:id="@+id/viewAnimatorSeekbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_below="@id/rel_layout"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_page_indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/grey_scrubber_progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/grey_scrubber_control"/>
</ViewAnimator>
```

Comment: Use seekBar startTime upto to 10 seconds in separate Thread where check boolean condition if user touched to seekBar or not. And stops if seekBar touched otherwise at last 10 seconds condition hide Seekbar. Upvote if get helpful idea.

Comment: onTopTrackingTouch call in main Thread, So You are using Thread.sleep(10000). It means you are blocking main Thread for 10 sec. So use Handler with delay instead of Thread.sleep

Comment: postDelayed solved the problem. But the animation does not run smoothly inside handler. Do you have any idea why?